# Variable times static number + variable

Tags: php, variables

Not 100% sure I can do this.. But I am wondering if it is possible. I want to be able to do something like this ;

```
    $a = 5
    $b = mt_rand(125,245); 
    $c = $a*1.0$a;
```

So A = 5 ( for an example, it will be different on different criteria, B is then the random number x 1.0 and the variable..

So this example would be `$c = $b*1.05`

But as the variable A will look at a specific column in a table it isn't always 5. Am I making this way too complex, is there a more simple way to do this?

I would prefer the table variable to NOT be `1.05` for example.. As it would be easier for me to display just 5

Comment: "B is then the random number x 1.0 and the variable" Multiplying by one leaves you with what you started with (modulo implicit type conversions) and what do you mean by "and the variable"? What is the operation "and" in this case?

Comment: If `$b` is some random number times *one*, then why can't you just do `$c = $a * $b`?

Comment: I need C to be XX% on top of the mt_rand sorry. So thats why I put 1.05. Which would be the variable +5%

Comment: Are you looking for `$c = $b * (1.0 + $a / 100.0)`? If `$a == 5` then `1.0 + $a / 100.0 == 1.05`, so therefore `$c` is `$b` increased by 5%.

Answer (score 3):

So there is no casting:

```
$a = 5;
$b = mt_rand(125,245);
$c = $b * (1 + ($a / 100));
```

Comment: this answer is better than mine if the un-altered multiplier (`1.0`) is an easy number and not `2/3`. -- +1

Answer (score 1):

you're on the right track,

```
$a = 5;
$b = mt_rand(125,245); 
$c = $b*(float)('1.0'.$a);
```

make the `1.0` portion a string, concatenate the contents of `$a` and then type juggle it back to a `float` and it should work how you're expecting.